# Does Dplyr groupby Sum all columns or can you specify R

Tags: r, dplyr

New to R and I found groupby but I am curious how I would sum almost all of the columns in my df. a few are text and date but most others are ones I would like to sum. I would like to groupby the first column team and sum the columns of my choice. How would I go about writing this?

[image]

Comment: Multiple ways to do this. You can use `select` to select specific columns and then use `summarise` or `summarise_all` or you can also use `summarise_at` etc. Check the documentation of those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some options, using a sample data set

```
df<- data.frame(
                Team= sample(c("Team A", "Team B","Team C"),50, replace= TRUE),
                A=sample(1:5,50, replace=TRUE),
                B=sample(3:5,50, replace=TRUE),
                C=sample(c("A","B","C"),50, replace=TRUE),
                D=sample(3:5,50, replace=TRUE))

  # Referencing by single column name             
df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarise(total=sum(A))

# Referencing multiple column names              
df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarise(totalA=sum(A), totalB= sum(B))


df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum) # throws an error since some columns are not numeric

df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  select(A,B,D) %>%  # select numeric columns first
  summarise_all(sum)


df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) #use summarise_if to select numeric columns
```